# Stprl from a dataframe to another

Tags: r

How is it possible having a dataframe like this:

```
df_words <- data.frame(words = c("4 Google", "5Amazon", "4sec"))
```

replace in the rows of a dataframe like this:

```
df <-  data.frame(id = c(1,2,4),  text = "Increase for 4 Google", "There is a slight decrease for 5Amazon", "I will need 4sec more"), stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

replace with the specific word the one listed in the df_words like this

```
"4 Google|5Amazon" -> "stock"
"4sec" -> time
```

Example of expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,4),  text = "Increase for stock", "There is a slight decrease for stock", "I will need time more"), stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the `stringi` library. Example:

```
library(stringi)
strings = c("Increase for 4 Google", "There is a slight decrease for 5Amazon", "I will need 4sec more")
patterns = c("4 Google", "5Amazon", "4sec")
replacements = c("stock", "stock", "time")
strings = stri_replace_all_fixed(strings,patterns,replacements)
```

However, you probably want to handle many stocks and many times, so you might be better off doing something like this:

```
stocks = c("4 Google", "5Amazon")
strings = stri_replace_all_fixed(strings,stocks,'stock')
strings = stri_replace_all_regex(strings,'\b[0-9]+sec\b',time)
```

`\b[0-9]+sec\b` is a regular expression meaning:

1. word boundary
2. one or more number characters
3. "sec"
4. word boundary

This will include strings such as "2sec" but exclude those such as "1sector"